# Is the Solidity compiler deterministic?

Tags: solidity, solc, compilation

I am aware that you have to specify the Solidity compiler version and whether or not you use the optimisation flag. But even with all that considered - is the compiler deterministic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least it *should* be deterministic. We eliminated some sources of non-determinism in May, so it now should always produce the same result on the same input, even on different platforms. If that is not the case, please report a bug.

Comment: The use of the word "should" is a little scary for high value/volume contracts. How to change the would "should" to "is"?